# Get-azkeyvaultaccesspolicy is not found

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

I am trying to fetch (just get) the list of access policy of my keyvault and somehow this powershell command is not working. It gives me the error as shown below:

WARNING: **Get-azkeyvaultaccesspolicy is not found**. The most similar Azure PowerShell command is:
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy
Get-azkeyvaultaccesspolicy : The term 'Get-azkeyvaultaccesspolicy' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I am not able to find any help with this, can someone please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/?view=azps-10.0.0#key-vault), it seems there is no Cmdlet named `Get-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy` in version 10.0.0 (latest version at the time of writing this answer).

What you can do is get the details of a KeyVault using [`Get-AzKeyVault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/get-azkeyvault?view=azps-10.0.0) and then read the access policies from [`AccessPolicies`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.keyvault.models.pskeyvault.accesspolicies?view=az-ps-latest#microsoft-azure-commands-keyvault-models-pskeyvault-accesspolicies) property.

Your code could be something like:

```
$kv = Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName "key-vault-name" -ResourceGroupName "resource-group-name"
$accessPolicies = $kv.AccessPolicies
# Do something with access policies...
```